# SSD emergency mode

Tags: boot, mount, ssd

I tried to boot after mounting a new SSD.

[image]

```
You are in emergency mode.
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `cat /etc/fstab`. It's that file that's corrupt by missing a number after `sda` or some other drive if your disk isn't corrupt